# Are there any "inspection" type functions in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In grid graphics there's a nice little function get.gpar() that prints the current graphic's parameters (things like fill, color, etc.). And I'm just curious if any similar sorts of convenience functions exist in ggplot2?

Here's a dumb example of get.gpar() if you haven't encountered it before:

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
get.gpar()  #prints default settings

pushViewport(viewport(gp = gpar(fill = "red")))  #change fill to red
get.gpar("fill")  #now the default "white" should've changed to "red"
```

Thanks!

Comment: But, but, but ... ggplot2 is built on top of grid.

Comment: it really depends what parameters you're after. Some can be hidden fairly deep, and require substantial effort to access.

Comment: cool, I had a feeling the answer would be, "yeah, sort of..." Thanks for the responses. I still <3 ggplot!

Comment: you specify what you want ggplot2 to do. if you need to introspect then you have no clue what you're doing and might as well be using crayons.

Comment: @hrbrmstr i agree that ggplot probably doesn't need this function -- it would be too hard to make for too little payoff. but if your logic was completely sound, then functions like str(), summary(), length(), dim(), help(), etc. would also be redundant. And we'd have no need for the word 'debugging'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at `?theme` we see a reference to `?theme_update` which also describes the `theme_get` function:

```
names(theme_get())
 [1] "line"                  "rect"                 
 [3] "text"                  "axis.title.x"         
 [5] "axis.title.x.top"      "axis.title.y"         
 [7] "axis.title.y.right"    "axis.text"      
# sniped the rest of the 57 item list of names in the current theme.
```

Like the lattice plotting system that preceded ggplot/ggplot2 the attributes of those theme types are held in lists, sometimes with attributes. The actual values of a few of them can be seen with:

```
> head( theme_get() )
$line
List of 6
 $ colour       : chr "black"
 $ size         : num 0.5
 $ linetype     : num 1
 $ lineend      : chr "butt"
 $ arrow        : logi FALSE
 $ inherit.blank: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element_line" "element"

$rect
List of 5
 $ fill         : chr "white"
 $ colour       : chr "black"
 $ size         : num 0.5
 $ linetype     : num 1
 $ inherit.blank: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element_rect" "element"
```

The help page for `?theme_set` shows how to replace either single items with `+.element` inside the list or replace an entire list with `%+replace%.element`. Work the examples on the page to get a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks, theme_get & _set seem like really handy functions!